# The use of XOR for removing character from string and finding duplicates

Tags: string, algorithm, duplicates, bit-manipulation, xor

The following questions are based on the use of XOR :

1. Given a string say of integers. The task at hand is to remove the
   given character from string.  I tried using XOR to solve it. eg
   `char str[] = "123456"` . Remove `4.` XOR the given character with
   the entire string. That character vanishes.

   ```
   XOR = (1^2^3^4^5^6) ^ 4
   ```

   However I am left with the XOR of the remaining characters.

   ```
   XOR = (1^2^3^5^6)
   ```

   Is there any method I could get the individual characters back?
2. I need to find and remove elements that have duplicates (including the elements themselves)

   eg. A = {1,9,8,2,2} then output should be {1,9,8} after removal

   However this will fail since 1^9 = 8. Hence (1^9)^8^2^2 gives empty array. Is there any alternative using XOR itself?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking here. Your notation is pretty confusing, so I don't know if you're trying to XOR all the elements together, or XORing each element with 4. Please edit your question to clarify, and provide code samples in an actual programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int num=4;
for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
    if(((str[i]-'0')^num) == 0)
        remove_number(i);
}
```

Comment: what's remove number?

Comment: remove_number(int) is a function which you can make in which you can just assign the index str[i]=0 so that you can know while printing that this index has been removed